# Most efficient way of appending/connecting one LinkedList to the back of another LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently trying to connect 2 separate LinkedList of the same type, and was wondering what is the most efficient way to do it with just the Java API LinkedList implementation (i.e without creating my own implementation of LinkedList)?

Comment: You can't do it more efficiently than adding the shorter one to the longer one 1-by-1. The built in `LinkedList` doesn't expose the APIs for linking nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an immutable list view that concatenates two lists, try this.

```
public class ConcatenatedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private final List<E> a, b;

    public ConcatenatedList(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return index < a.size() ? a.get(index) : b.get(index - a.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return a.size() + b.size();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> listA = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2));
    List<Integer> listB = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
    List<Integer> joined = new ConcatenatedList<>(listA, listB);
    System.out.println(joined);
}
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This concatenation is O(1).